# How do I get rid of "cannot load compass error" in vim?

Tags: vim, sass, compass

I'm new to sass. When I load a .scss file in vim, I get a `Cannot load compass` error upon save. Looks like it's getting generated from syntastic. I installed compass with `gem install compass` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with:

`gem uninstall sass`

`gem uninstall compass`

then

`gem install compass` (which also installs older version of sass)